# Initializing structs over 12 bytes gets SIGILL

Tags: android, crash, clang, cross-compiling, armv7

I'm trying to run a cross compiled executable on the following emulator

`system-images;android-21;google_apis;armeabi-v7a`

I have the following *Makefile*

```
NDK=/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
bam: bam.c
    $(NDK)/bin/clang --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 \
        --gcc-toolchain=$(NDK) --sysroot=$(NDK)/sysroot \
        -g -DANDROID  -march=armv7-a -mthumb -std=gnu99 -o bam.o -c bam.c
    $(NDK)/bin/clang --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 \
        --gcc-toolchain=$(NDK) --sysroot=$(NDK)/sysroot \
        -g -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mthumb bam.o -o bam
    adb push bam /cache/bam
    adb shell "/cache/bam && echo Passed"
```

The following *bam.c* crashes on the initialization of `bar`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    char d;
};

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    struct foo bar = {15,7};
    if (bar.a != 0) printf("Happy\n");
    return 0;
}
```

in the following way

```
$ make bam
/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk-cur/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang \
        --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 \
        --gcc-toolchain=/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk-cur/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 \
        --sysroot=/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk-cur/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot \
        -g -DANDROID  -march=armv7-a -mthumb -std=gnu99 -o bam.o -c bam.c
/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk-cur/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang \
        --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 \
        --gcc-toolchain=/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk-cur/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 \
        --sysroot=/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk-cur/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot \
        -g -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mthumb bam.o -o bam
adb push bam /cache/bam
bam: 1 file pushed. 0.2 MB/s (7788 bytes in 0.043s)
adb shell "/cache/bam && echo Passed"
Illegal instruction
```

When i remove the last char field so the *bam.c* looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    //char d;
};

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    struct foo bar = {15,7};
    if (bar.a != 0) printf("Happy\n");
    return 0;
}
```

it behaves as expected.

```
make bam
/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 \
        --gcc-toolchain=/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot \
        -g -DANDROID  -march=armv7-a -mthumb -std=gnu99 -o bam.o -c bam.c
/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 \
        --gcc-toolchain=/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot \
        -g -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mthumb bam.o -o bam
adb push bam /cache/bam
bam: 1 file pushed. 0.7 MB/s (7756 bytes in 0.011s)
adb shell "/cache/bam && echo Passed"
Happy
Passed
```

What is it about initializing structs > a certain size that i'm missing here?
In case it matters, i'm building on

`$ uname -a
Linux kdev 4.15.0-72-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 26 12:20:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

For the record, this is a repro of a problem that i'm having when statically linking to icui18n and trying to fire up a regex.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved by using an older version of the NDK, r20b in my case.
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases

Comment: Maybe with a little more explanation (the problem and way that solution worked) the answer can fit better

Comment: yeah sorry about that Daniel, but I really have no idea, I just had the same issue and using a previous version of the NDK worked out, that's all ¯\_(ツ)_/¯